# htaccess redirect no-www to www (multidomains)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect non www URL to WWW URL for multidomains

here is what I need exactly

http://example.com should goto www.example.com

http://example.de  should goto www.example.de

All the above geographilay domains should do to their corresponding domains with www (.com .de and .uk are in same server)

Comment: I have identical situation for a multidomain site with many domains. Did you get it to work? Share your solution please?

Comment: Nevermind... got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} ^(([^\.]+)\.([a-z\.]+))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This has no effect for me.

Answer (score 0):

All credit go to MrWhite his [solution here](https://serverfault.com/questions/877100/htaccess-replaces-full-url-instead-of-request-uri):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```